# Aligned rank transform on time series data

Tags: time-series, anova, spss

I have some time-series data that I wish to test to see if a certain factor has an effect. There are few samples per time step (10 on average), but the whole time-series has 306 samples. When divided into groups based upon a factor the result is non-normal and non homogeneous. I wish to test the effect of the factor, and if possible, determine a linear trend over the time-series accounting for this effect.

To test the effect, I performed an aligned rank transform on the data, then used an ANOVA. However this does not take into account time. To do this I tried a General Linear Model on the transformed data using the factor as a fixed effect and time as a covariate. Does this sound correct?

What is the correct way to include time information in a factorial analysis when the number of samples per unit time is quite low?

Edit: Additional information:

**Time Series**
[image: Time Series]

**Factor**
[image: Factor]

Note: software used is SPSS, stats experience is beginner.

**Download Data Here:**

[Data](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8184720/SPSS/data_spss.csv)

Comment: please clarify "There are few samples per time step (10 on average), but the whole time-series has 306 samples. " Actually show the data and that might help.

Comment: Can you please present a table of values of three columns showing time , output value  and factor .

Comment: @IrishStat Rather than a table, I have provided a link to a CSV file of the data. I tried to paste in the values into this post but I would have had to format each line.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the aligned rank transform, but it seems utilizing multi level models (i.e. `MIXED` in SPSS command lingo) may be a fruitful approach to be able to incorporate any temporal trends (perhaps in the original units instead of the ranked units).

Comment: I have looked at the data and I am still a little confused. Are you monitoring a particular sample/item over time while applying a "factor" at each point in time or sometimes not applying a factor or maybe not even observing/recording each unique sample/item at certain points in time ? Time series analysis is the study of possible "time" effects on individual items.

Comment: @IrishStat The samples are a compilation of many individual data sets. Some samples are repeated, most are not. I don't think there is anything meaningful except for simple descriptives, and perhaps the factor analysis on the whole set without regard for time. Not sure how to show that the data is no good, if you have some hints for that, it would be equally valuable.

Comment: P.S., we did not design the studies, the results were obtained from the literature.

Comment: P.P.S. Each sample is being made at a particular location, and we are interested any trends occurring over then entire area.

Comment: Ok . Is it possible for you to repost your data to include the location specifier even though you are not ultimately interested in this effect ?

Comment: @IrishStat Thansk, I have updated the csv with location numbers.